# how to get json data in 2 Modal class using GSON and Volley Android

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

> i have 2 Modal classes like Result and another is Student
>   i want to get all the json response in two modal class using gson i try this way
>
> *json response :- {"success":"1","request":"/api/v1/getmarketsummaries","message":"","result":[{"MarketID":"18","LastPrice":"0.01458900","Change":"-1.10","HighPrice":"0.01497193","LowPrice":"0.01453000","Volume":"5.27365150","BTCVolume":"5.27365150","TradeCount":"344","BidPrice":"0.01458012","AskPrice":"0.01470990","BuyOrderCount":"228","SellOrderCount":"864"},{"MarketID":"43","LastPrice":"0.00004443","Change":"0.00","HighPrice":"0.00000000","LowPrice":"0.00000000","Volume":"0.00000000","BTCVolume":"0.00000000","TradeCount":"0","BidPrice":"0.00003363","AskPrice":"0.00004433","BuyOrderCount":"29","SellOrderCount":"432"}]} *

how to set all response  in modal class using **Gson**

```html
    Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Gson gson = new Gson();

Result result = gson.fromJson(response,Result.class);

> but not able to get that data so, how can i make it possible...

```html
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("MarketID")
    @Expose
    private String marketID;
    @SerializedName("LastPrice")
    @Expose
    private String lastPrice;
    @SerializedName("Change")
    @Expose
    private String change;
    @SerializedName("HighPrice")
    @Expose
    private String highPrice;
    @SerializedName("LowPrice")
    @Expose
    private String lowPrice;
    @SerializedName("Volume")
    @Expose
    private String volume;
    @SerializedName("BTCVolume")
    @Expose
    private String bTCVolume;
    @SerializedName("TradeCount")
    @Expose
    private String tradeCount;
    @SerializedName("BidPrice")
    @Expose
    private String bidPrice;
    @SerializedName("AskPrice")
    @Expose
    private String askPrice;
    @SerializedName("BuyOrderCount")
    @Expose
    private String buyOrderCount;
    @SerializedName("SellOrderCount")
    @Expose
    private String sellOrderCount;

    public String getMarketID() {
        return marketID;
    }

    public void setMarketID(String marketID) {
        this.marketID = marketID;
    }

    public String getLastPrice() {
        return lastPrice;
    }

    public void setLastPrice(String lastPrice) {
        this.lastPrice = lastPrice;
    }

    public String getChange() {
        return change;
    }

    public void setChange(String change) {
        this.change = change;
    }

    public String getHighPrice() {
        return highPrice;
    }

    public void setHighPrice(String highPrice) {
        this.highPrice = highPrice;
    }

    public String getLowPrice() {
        return lowPrice;
    }

    public void setLowPrice(String lowPrice) {
        this.lowPrice = lowPrice;
    }

    public String getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public String getBTCVolume() {
        return bTCVolume;
    }

    public void setBTCVolume(String bTCVolume) {
        this.bTCVolume = bTCVolume;
    }

    public String getTradeCount() {
        return tradeCount;
    }

    public void setTradeCount(String tradeCount) {
        this.tradeCount = tradeCount;
    }

    public String getBidPrice() {
        return bidPrice;
    }

    public void setBidPrice(String bidPrice) {
        this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
    }

    public String getAskPrice() {
        return askPrice;
    }

    public void setAskPrice(String askPrice) {
        this.askPrice = askPrice;
    }

    public String getBuyOrderCount() {
        return buyOrderCount;
    }

    public void setBuyOrderCount(String buyOrderCount) {
        this.buyOrderCount = buyOrderCount;
    }

    public String getSellOrderCount() {
        return sellOrderCount;
    }

    public void setSellOrderCount(String sellOrderCount) {
        this.sellOrderCount = sellOrderCount;
    }

}
```

```html
public class Market {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private String success;
    @SerializedName("request")
    @Expose
    private String request;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = null;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json response is invalid. it has extra '}' before ']'.

```
json response :- {"success":"1","request":"/api/v1/getmarketsummaries","message":"","result":[{"MarketID":"18","LastPrice":"0.01458900","Change":"-1.10","HighPrice":"0.01497193","LowPrice":"0.01453000","Volume":"5.27365150","BTCVolume":"5.27365150","TradeCount":"344","BidPrice":"0.01458012","AskPrice":"0.01470990","BuyOrderCount":"228","SellOrderCount":"864"},{"MarketID":"43","LastPrice":"0.00004443","Change":"0.00","HighPrice":"0.00000000","LowPrice":"0.00000000","Volume":"0.00000000","BTCVolume":"0.00000000","TradeCount":"0","BidPrice":"0.00003363","AskPrice":"0.00004433","BuyOrderCount":"29","SellOrderCount":"432"}]}
```

And also Result & Market classes are defined in reverse. Market class has list of Result. So response should be parsed into Market object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Market market = gson.fromJson(response,Market.class);
    List<Result> result = market.getResult();
```

Comment: son response is invalid. it has extra '}' before ']'. its my typing mistake now i get that data.